# Robot framework - how to work with developer tools in chrome during test run?

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, robotframework

Is there any possibility to leave dev tools (inspector) opened during a robot test run?
I included a manual step into my "semi-automated" test in which I open the dev tools (F12), but after click on `PASS` for the `Execute Manual Step` other automated steps follow and the dev tool is immediately automatically closed.
Just overview of the structure of my test:

```
Semi-automated robot test
    do some automated steps
    execute manual step     open developers console
    do some other automated steps
    execute manual step     check something in dev console
```

I have no idea how to handle the dev tools during robot test. Even if I open the dev tool in separate window during the manual step, it is still closed during automated steps...

Thanks for any idea :-)

Comment: Why do you need to keep devconsole open? What exactly you want check during test run?

Comment: I need to check some request filling in network tab and if I open it AFTER the steps are done, there is nothing..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It isn't possible. From [ChromeDriver help center](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/help/devtools-window-keeps-closing)

> When you open the DevTools window, ChromeDriver is automatically
>   disconnected. When ChromeDriver receives a command, if disconnected,
>   it will attempt to close the DevTools window and reconnect.
>
> If you need to inspect something in DevTools, the best you can do now
>   is pause your test so that ChromeDriver won't close DevTools. When you
>   are done inspecting things in Chrome, you can unpause your test and
>   ChromeDriver will close the window and continue.

Answer (score 2):

As an example to the answer of @Guy you can use the [Dialogs](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/Dialogs.html) library in Robot Framework

```
*** Settings ***
Library    Dialogs

*** Test Cases ***
test case
   Pause Execution    Please Press OK to Continue.
```

This will then show you the following alert type of box.

[image]

Comment: I am using Dialogs for manual step execution, but this command will not help me, because I don't want to pause the execution, I need the automated steps to be executed...As  Guy mentioned, there is not really a way to do what I need and how I need. Becsuse I need to inspect the dev tools right DURING automated step execution...

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to get information about `HTTP`-requests that were sent during your `Seelenium` test-run you might need to add below code, that will constantly print out logs with required info:

```
import logging
import http.client as client

client.HTTPConnection.debuglevel = 1
logging.basicConfig()
logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
requests_log = logging.getLogger("selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection")
requests_log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
requests_log.propagate = True
```